# How to remove a number from 'Recents' on iPhone, rather deleting all?

Tags: iphone

Since many days I am trying to achieve this, but I can only delete/ clear all recent dial, received phone numbers.

Is there an option/ hack to delete only one number at a time on my iPhone ?

I have iPhone 3GS

Comment: Just keep your girlfriend from seeing your phone and you'll be all right.

Comment: I don't remember their names, but I remember seeing 3-5 Cydia apps over time that did just this.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to wait for iOS 5 to be able to do what you are asking. I'm running iOS 5 and I'm able to do this without a jailbreak.
[image: iOS 5 Developer Preview]

Answer (score 1):

If your iPhone is jailbroken you can install the package [Ixtension](http://ixtension.com/) (it's $9.99 from the BigBossRepo)

Disclaimer: I'm in now way affiliated with the developers.

Comment: No, my iPhone is not jailbroken and I don't want to.

Comment: @garikapati I highly doubt you can do it without jailbreaking. Maybe through some desktop software and syncing back and forth.

Comment: @Cawas I was looking if somebody in the millions of iPhone owners did that.... so I can get help.

Comment: @garikapati I wish you best of luck! ;) as for bruno suggestion, there is at least one cheaper option on cydia: ***Recent/CallLog Delete*** ($ 1.49) but **Mobile Log** is great indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Go to 'recents' on phone. Tap 'edit' in top right hand corner of screen.
You will then have like no entry sign type symbol at the left of each number in recents. Tap the no entry sign by the number you wish to delete, a box will appear to the right of that number asking you if you wish to delete it, then type delete.

Comment: The above works but it also deletes that number from the contacts list.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt iOS allows you to enumerate recent calls through standard iOS apps.  I would suspect that through jail-breaking you could make an app yourself that could do it.  Other than that, I doubt it's possible at all.